# Python connection with the database SQL

Tags: python, sql

I am getting an error with this code.

```
db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","ahmed","Properties")

cursor=db.cursor()

query="""INSERT INTO Properties (Property_Num, 
                                 Published_Date, 
                                 Title,
                                 Price,
                                 Bedroom,
                                 Agency_Fee, 
                                 Bathroom,
                                 Size,
                                 Prop_ref,
                                 Furnished_status,
                                 Rent_payment,
                                 Building_info,
                                 Amenities,
                                 Trade_name,
                                 Licence, 
                                 RERA_ID,
                                 Phone_info,
                                 Short_link) 
values (?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,
        ?,?,?)"""

cursor.execute(query,(count_curr,
                      date_result,
                      title_result,
                      price_result,
                      bedroom_result,
                      agencyfee_result,
                      bathroom_result,
                      size_result,
                      propertyref_result,
                      furnished_result,
                      rent_is_paid_result,
                      building_result,
                      Amenities_result,
                      tradename_result,
                      licencenum_result,
                      reraid_result,
                      phone_result,
                      link_result))
db.commit()
```

The error is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/Dropbox/business skills/Project5- Webscraping/property.py", line 238, in <module>
    extract_data()
  File "/home/ahmed/Dropbox/business skills/Project5- Webscraping/property.py", line 214, in extract_data
    cursor.execute(query,(count_curr,date_result,title_result,price_result,bedroom_result,agencyfee_result,bathroom_result,size_result,propertyref_result,furnished_result,rent_is_paid_result,building_result,Amenities_result,tradename_result,licencenum_result,reraid_result,phone_result,link_result))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have tried everything but it is just not working. I don't know what the problem is. The column types in the database are all `VARCHAR`.................

```
   results of the variables are this (with some details)
    Property Number:  1 
    Published date:  3rd February 2014
    Title:  Hot offer ! Well maintained   1 bed for rent in Al Samar 1
    Price:  85,000
    Size of the property:  840.00 SqFt
    Property reference in Dubizel:  HP-R-2157
    Furnished status:  No
    Rent payment:  Yearly
    Building info:  Al Samar 1
    Amenitities:  Built in Wardrobes,Pets Allowed
    Trade name:  AL HABTOOR PROPERTIES (L L C )
    RERA ID #:  1171
    Phone information: ‪0508550594‪

    types of the these variables not string
  <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>]
```

to convert them to string after the re initializing (when the results are replaced by the initial values "") the type of the variable changes.

Comment: You shouldn't tag Python questions as PHP and expect immediate response. You could have also used the waiting time to format your code and stack trace and make them readable.

Comment: thank you! I hope someone replies

Comment: Try to use ? instead of %s

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting . it gives this error now gunzapper

Comment: every tag is initialized like this count_curr=""  and the types in the database is varchar

Comment: Try to use ? and eventually cast your variable... str(something), int(otherstuff)

Comment: mmmmhhh.... in the example of the documentation there isn't the columns list in insertion, but only the table, try to do query="""INSERT INTO Properties  
values (?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?)"""

Comment: did and edited the question

Comment: Print the values of count_curr, date_result, title_result, etc. And share the result in a pastebin like site.

Comment: and print also the types print map(type, (a_lot_of_things))

Comment: check the values in the edited version (ignore the coding format)

Comment: Try: cursor.execute(query,map(str, (count_curr, etc...)))

Comment: And an other thing... you print only 13/18 variables... why?

Comment: types are also displayed. and yes, this is going in a while loop. in different loops, different results come hence in this first loop, 13 outputs are there. does it make the error?

Comment: cursor.execute(query,map(str, (count_curr.. --> executed this but still same error

Comment: Okay for str... but, do you use the same query to insert 13 values on 18 neither 18 on 18?

Comment: same query for every loop whether 18 or 13

Comment: other 5 variables are simple empty "" strings so i believe they will be just stored as "" (empty)

Comment: for missing values try to use a default value like "no info" or simpler " ". Insert always 18 values

Comment: and you insert also the empty values, isn't it?

Comment: I am initializing all the variables with "".?

Comment: only the ones that you don't have the value to insert... you must put explictally all values inside, either empty strings

Comment: with all the values initialized as "", the results (13 in the first loop) will be replaced and result of the 5 will be "" strings. so i believe every variable is somehow having some value (empty "" or result)

Comment: It look a bit unpythonic, but I don't know the context, however try... the important thing is to have 18 values to insert inside, no matter the way you done to make this.

Comment: "" is not considered to be a value?

Comment: IMHO it's a valid value, but depends also about the costrinctions of the table... of course

Comment: I would tell that it's nasty initialize some things and after reinitialize it, I prefer to do all in one step, but it's only my style preference, don't care about it

Comment: I just simply commented out the code and gave each variable a value of "a". All the 18 variables with the value of "a" gets inserted but still the same error lol. my mind is blowing up

Comment: i think something is wrong with the query

Comment: I think that we forgot something stupid and that you'll find the solution after, when you are more relaxed

Comment: Ah i got it. wait. please check the edit post in a while

Comment: check the last part of the post when i run print map(type, (count_curr........ after the results. the types are changing lol ahhh

Comment: If I understand, follow what you wrote, Bedroom_result is your first empty value, and "" in your system is encoded as unicode string  Strange (Are you use 2.* or 3.*?)... but probably no matter,and first to decode it, try to pass it "no value"s, instead of ""s